# Which Goddess is this whose idols were discovered recently in Kashmir?

Tags: identification-request, devi, durga, kashmir

There was recent news about the **accidental discovery of two idols of Devi Durga in Kashmir**, one of which has been dated 1200 years old while the other is 1300 years old.

- [1,200-year-old Goddess Durga Idol Found from River Bed in Jammu & Kashmir](https://www.news18.com/news/buzz/1200-year-old-goddess-durga-idol-discovered-from-river-bed-in-jammu-kashmir-4151816.html)
- [Ancient Durga idol found in J&K’s Budgam - Hindustan Times](https://www.hindustantimes.com/cities/chandigarh-news/ancient-durga-idol-found-in-j-k-s-budgam-101638300815851.html)

The news bites have labeled her as Durga since she is sitting on a lion's throne. But unlike Ma Durga both the idols show her with just two hands carrying a lotus in one and possibly a decorated sword or what seems to me like a plant stalk in the other hand. Please see the images below:

[image]

[image]

**So I want to understand if this depiction is true of Goddess Durga or is it some other form of Devi?**

Comment: It is possible that it is some form of Devi Tripurasundari, since Tripurasundari bears the Ikshu Kodanda (sugarcane bow) and the Pushpa Bana (floral arrows); although Tripurasundari has four hands and the above deity has only two.

Comment: It's entirely different but take a look at this - https://edition.cnn.com/style/article/india-stolen-yogini-statue-return-intl-scli/index.html

Comment: Yes I thought so too that it may be a representation of Goddess Tripura Sundari that's why my question.. the Yogini idol is interesting too but I don't think they were worshipped as goddesses as claimed in multiple articles.

Answer (score 1):

Kashmir has a Shaivat tradition and as she is sitting on lion throne, that is Singhvahini...makes it a depiction of Durga. I think the popularity of Tripurasundari was more in Nepal region.

Comment: There are many forms of the goddess who ride a lion so I am looking for a more concrete identification